# How to test for different usernames and passwords for same website using Selenium WebDriver elegantly?

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following example code that logs in to Facebook using a username and password,

```
@Test
    public void fb() {
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
        ffprofile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "iPhone"); //this will change the user agent which will open mobile browser
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(400, 800)); //just to change the window size so that it will look like mobile ;)
        driver.get("http://www.fb.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("user1");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    }
```

Next I have 5 more Facebook profiles say user2, user3, user4, user5 and user6. I want to log in to Facebook using these profiles as well to do some automated testing.

My question is should I re-write the above code 5 more times for different usernames, or is there any other elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keyword based testing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword-driven_testing You would repeat the test for a given set of keywords (in this case, user / password pairs). Your function would need to take in the values as parameters: `public void fb(String user, String password) {... .sendKeys(user).... sendKeys(password)....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which test framework you are using, so

- If this is JUnit, you can use [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests). They would allow you to run this same test you have with various parameters:

  ```
  @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
  public class LoginTest {
      @Parameters
      public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
          return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
           { "user1", "password" }, 
           { "user2", "password" } //...
      });
  }

  private String username, password;

  public LoginTest(String username, String password) {
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
  }

  @Test
  public void fb() {
      // most of it won't change, except:
      driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(username);
      driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(password);
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Nunit has a [similar concept](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5)
- Finally, if you cannot use any of this goodness, you could just create a function that represents your login function and call it from 5 different tests. That way you still have some redundancy of the test call, but not the code to login:

  ```
  private WebDriver driver;

  public void login(String username, String password) {
      driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(username);
      driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(password);
      driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
  }

  // Move code to init driver to run before every test
  @Before
  public void initDriver() {
      FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
      ffprofile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "iPhone"); //this will change the user agent which will open mobile browser
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(400, 800)); //just to change the window size so that it will look like mobile ;)
      driver.get("http://www.fb.com/");
  }

  @Test
  public void fb1() {
      login("user1", "password");
  }

  @Test
  public void fb2() {
      login("user2", "password");
  }

  // etc
  ```

By the way: initializing driver **once per class** is a better idea, since profile creation / starting browser is an expensive operation, if you have many tests, it may slow you down. You also should consider **logging out** after every test, so that you next login is clean.

Comment: I am using JUnit here. However, your last suggested method has seemed to solve my problem. Thanks!